# Is there a way to cache JSON on client side for limited time in order to avoid making 2 GET requests to the API if the user visits the same page twice

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Imagine this scenario - A user visits their profile page on URL `/user/username` and the component that loads on this URL has to make 1 GET request to the API in order to obtain the information about the user with that username. So far so good, however, if the user visits another URL and then decides to come back to the profile page with URL `/user/username`, the component makes a new GET request for the same information that it got earlier which leads to 2 drawbacks - the information doesn't appear instantly as the component has to wait for the GET request and I'm making a second call to the API.

This is why I am wondering if it's possible to somehow cache that information so that when the user visits his profile page again, the component wouldn't have to make a second GET request. Also this cached information should be able to expire after a certain amount of time like an hour so that it is never inaccurate.

Is this achievable and worth it?

Comment: Give https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/http-caching a read

Comment: @SudhakarRS that is static caching, i guess this question is about api response caching

Answer (score 0):

You can use browser [Local Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) or WebSql or [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) to store data on browser but be careful, they has limit size.

You should cache data on [server side](https://medium.com/@bahung1221/caching-api-responses-with-expressjs-middleware-an-simple-way-to-speed-up-your-site-308ac73f357f) instead client side, by this way you will have more privilege to manage your data (caching size, flush cache, ...)

Answer (score 0):

I personally would first try the http-caching solution as mentioned by "Sudhakar RS", but next I would try session storage. There is [a vue-sessionstorage plugin](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-sessionstorage) as well. Of course your data then would be valid for the session. Should your session be longer than the hour you mention you would have to manually handle that as part of the data you save with a timestamp. There is a sizelimit of I think 5MB for **all** session storage data. If you need more then I would go with what "Hung Nguyen" suggested.